# Magetno 2 order grid pagination page number set from where we open details page of order

Tags: magento2

Suppose we are viewing 2-page number records and open that 1 particular order in details page now press back button from order view page so this should return page 2 records but **it throw me on page 1**.

Return page - let us say search results in 100 orders and 20 per order page. If we are on the third page and we open an order on returning or while going back it.

goes to the first page instead of the third page where we came from.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We have created these features using one extra buttton in order view page when you click on privious button then it will return you where from you come on that page and back button will return you on 1 page of your order grid.

I will guide you also how will we can over write magento 2 base ui js file using mixin js.
firstly you need create one module.

**app/code/[vendor]/[moduleName]/registration.php**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_Modulename',
    __DIR__
);
```

create composer file in your module root folder.

**app/code/[vendor]/[moduleName]/composer.json**

```
    {
    "name": "vendor_/modulename",
    "description": "Vendor Modulename",
    "require": {
      "php": "~5.6.0|7.0.2|~7.0.6",
      "magento/module-store": "0.74.0-beta4",
      "magento/module-theme": "0.74.0-beta4",
      "magento/module-widget": "0.74.0-beta4",
      "magento/module-backend": "0.74.0-beta4",
      "magento/module-catalog": "0.74.0-beta4",
      "magento/module-email": "0.74.0-beta4",
      "magento/module-ui": "0.74.0-beta4",
      "magento/module-variable": "0.74.0-beta4",
      "magento/module-media-storage": "0.74.0-beta4",
      "magento/framework": "0.74.0-beta4",
      "magento/magento-composer-installer": "*"
    },
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "version": "0.74.0-beta4",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "extra": {
        "map": [
            [
                "*",
                "Vendor/Modulename"
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

Now create etc directory

**app/code/[vendor]/[moduleName]/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Modulename" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

And now we are going to overwrite magento vendor sale block file using preference you need to create di.xml

**app/code/[vendor]/[moduleName]/etc/adminhtml/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
        <preference for="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View" />
    </config>
```

now we are going to overwrite magento sales module block file because we are going to add new button on order view page.

**app/code/[vendor]/[moduleName]/Block/Adminhtml/Order/**

```
    <?php

namespace [vendor]/[moduleName]/Block/Adminhtml/Order/;

class View extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Container {
    protected $_coreRegistry = null;

    protected $_salesConfig;

    protected $_reorderHelper;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Config $salesConfig,
        \Magento\Sales\Helper\Reorder $reorderHelper,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_reorderHelper = $reorderHelper;
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
        $this->_salesConfig = $salesConfig;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);

        $this->addButton(
            'previous_page',
            [
                'label' => __('Previous'),
                'class' => 'cancel',
                'onclick' => "setLocation('{$this->getPreviousUrl()}')"
            ]
        );
    }

    public function getBackUrl()
    {
        if ($this->getOrder() && $this->getOrder()->getBackUrl()) {
            return $this->getOrder()->getBackUrl()."?previous=no";
        }

        return $this->getUrl('sales/*/')."?previous=no";
    }

    public function getPreviousUrl() {
        if ($this->getOrder() && $this->getOrder()->getBackUrl()) {
            return $this->getOrder()->getBackUrl()."?previous=yes";
        }

        return $this->getUrl('sales/*/')."?previous=yes";
    }

}
```

Now it's time to play with some js code

**app/code/[vendor]/[moduleName]/view/adminhtml/requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Ui/js/grid/paging/paging': {
                '[Vendor]_[ModuleName]/js/grid/paging/paging': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

This is the main logic we are going to use those method only which we need 
for these features only.and these features is allowed only when we use mixins js.

**app/code/[vendor]/[moduleName]/view/adminhtml/web/js/grid/paging/paging.js**

```
define([
    'ko',
    'underscore',
    'mageUtils',
    'uiLayout'
], function (ko, _, utils, layout) {
    'use strict';
    return function (Element) {
        return Element.extend({
            initObservable: function () {
                this._super()
                    .track([
                        'totalSelected',
                        'totalRecords',
                        'pageSize',
                        'pages',
                        'current'
                    ]);

                this._current = ko.pureComputed({
                    read: ko.getObservable(this, 'current'),

                    /**
                     * Validates page change according to user's input.
                     * Sets current observable to result of validation.
                     * Calls reload method then.
                     */
                    write: function (value) {
                        jQuery.cookie('currentPageNumber',value, { path: '/' });
                        this.setPage(value)
                            ._current.notifySubscribers(this.current);
                    },

                    owner: this
                });

                return this;
            },
            next: function () {
                var param = this.getParams('previous');
                if(param == 'yes'){
                    jQuery.cookie('currentPageNumber',this.current + 1, { path: '/' });
                }

                this.setPage(this.current + 1);

                return this;
            },
            prev: function () {
                var param = this.getParams('previous');
                if(param == 'yes'){
                    jQuery.cookie('currentPageNumber',this.current - 1, { path: '/' });
                }
                this.setPage(this.current - 1);

                return this;
            },
            setPage: function (value) {
                var param = this.getParams('previous');
                if(param == 'yes'){
                    value = jQuery.cookie('currentPageNumber');
                }
                this.current = this.normalize(value);

                return this;            
            },
            getParams: function (k) {
                 var p={};
                location.search.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi,function(s,k,v){p[k]=v})
                return k?p[k]:p;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

After this all process please run below commands :

**please run this command firstly after that all magento command :**

***rm -rf pub/static/adminhtml/***

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:clean
```